# Does the host USB speed affect data transfer between two external ports on USB hubs?

Tags: usb, file-transfer, usb-hub

When traveling, I want to transfer RAW files from my camera (on CFExpress cards) to an external SSD (as a backup).
Due to limited space, I am not taking a laptop with me, but only a tablet.

The following hardware will be used:
**CFExpress card:** Angelbird AV Pro SE (read: `1,700 MB/s`)
**CFExpress reader:** SanDisk Pro-Reader (USB3.1 Gen2 -> `1,250 MB/s`)
**Tablet:** Lenovo Tab P12 Pro (USB 3.1 -> `625 MB/s`)
**SSD:** SanDisk Extreme Pro Portable (write: `2,000 MB/s`)

I now have the following question:

If I use a USB hub on the tablet to connect both the CFx card and the SSD, **does the USB-C port on the tablet become a bottleneck** because all the data has to flow "through" the tablet first, or does the switching directly take place in the hub?
If there are differences between hubs, how do I find out which hub I have to use to get the highest possible speed (10 Gbit/s, `1,250 MB/s`)?
Is there a special designation for the operating modes of such a hub or do I simply have to buy a slightly more expensive hub?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Regards
Johannes

Comment: There are a number of items in series that *might* be a bottleneck. Does one predominate, or do they all slow down transfer? The best way to find out is to test that **on your particular system**. Try transferring perhaps a hundred files of about the same size as your image files (if both RAW and JPEG, the batch should contain both) to get an answer for *your* circumstances.

Comment: `does the USB-C port on the tablet become a bottleneck` Yes. You can't "direct copy" between hub ports because you need to read data from the source drive to your system memory (RAM) and write data from it to your destination drive. And in reality, it's pretty ideal already if it can copy at a rate like 450MB/s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USB hubs are not really like network switches, they're more like splitters.

A USB hub connects to a single primary USB port on a host device that controls the communication. It sends the signal from that one port to multiple secondary ports, each of which can be connected to a different client device. The secondary ports [can't talk directly to each other](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Limitations), they can only talk back and forth with the primary host. The host is responsible for controlling the communication, so to copy from one USB storage device to another, the data has to travel from one device through the host, then to the other device.

Based solely on the numbers you provided it would be likely that the tablet would be the bottleneck, but keep in mind that advertised speeds for devices are rarely realistic, and subject to variables beyond the speed of the packets. For example, a hard drive may be capable of high speeds, but only over a sustained time with continuous reading. If you are copying a large number of small files, you may see much slower results.

Your best bet for finding out what they're capable of is to actually try using them and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. 

I am aware that caches run full and the transfer speed drops with small files. My point was more to show what " category" the devices are in, and that the theoretical maximum of the tablet is much lower than the other devices.